# eliminating duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I want to pull users that only have ONE deviceID in a given month.
Let's say I have the following table:

```
User    Device ID
Greg    1
Greg    2
Mike    3
Laura   4
Laura   5
Lisa    6
George  7
Peter   8
Paul    9
Paul    10
Jane    11
```

I only want to see Users who have ONLY one deviceID. so in this case Mike, Lisa, George, Peter and Jane. Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: You'll wanna use [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thanks @sp_BlitzErik, what If I want to count the number of users with only one device ID? Im confused as to how to write that query. I am very new to SQL

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Erik's comment.

Reference:

- [SELECT - GROUP BY- Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SELECT - HAVING    (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.device
> GO
> CREATE TABLE dbo.device
>  (
>   userName nvarchar(128), 
>   device_ID int
>   );
> GO
> INSERT INTO dbo.device
>   (userName, device_ID)
> VALUES
>   ('Greg', 1),
>   ('Greg', 2),
>   ('Mike', 3),
>   ('Laura', 4),
>   ('Laura', 5),
>   ('Lisa', 6),
>   ('George', 7),
>   ('Peter', 8),
>   ('Paul', 9),
>   ('Paul', 10),
>   ('Jane', 11);
> GO
>
> --uncomment the line with COUNT if you want to see the count of device
> SELECT 
>   userName
>   --COUNT(device_id) AS numberOfDevice
> FROM dbo.device
> GROUP BY userName
> HAVING COUNT(device_id)=1;
> ```